# Present simple or present continuous in emails?

Tags: tenses

Suppose I get home and find an email from a friend that was sent while I was out. I reply by apologising that I didn't respond earlier since I was out. Is it better to say

> "It's only now that I find your email, I've been out."

or

> "It's only now that I'm finding your email, I've been out."

Comment: "I just found your email / now " or "I only just found your email / now" might be simpler?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! My question was a technical one, namely distinguishing between the present simple and the present continuous, as stated in the headline. I knew the present simple was the better of the two options, I only wanted to have a few other opinions. The construction I chose was deliberately pedantic, so as to only admit of those two possibilities (and maybe also the present perfect). I was in no doubt that "I've only just seen your email" was a more natural way of putting it, but once again, the point was to distinguish between the present simple and the present continuous.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get really technical, you're at the point of replying, so you're no longer "finding" the email; you've already found it.

Given that, if I **had to choose** between the two, I'd use the following:

> "It is only now that I find your email."

However, neither of your options read very easily - they both sound somewhat forced. If I was in your position, I would write something like this:

> "I've only just seen your email."

Comment: This sounds so unnatural to my ear.  Pedantic.

Comment: @aparente001, Dan asked which sounds better so I've stated which of the two I think is the best and provided the nearest alternative. Personally I think both sound unnatural and would write something like: "I've only just seen your email." But that wasn't the question was it?...

Comment: "I've only just seen your email" sounds great (and more British and elegant than my clumsy Americanism).  I think you should add it to your answer, along with your caveat.  Not all English language learners find their way to ELL, and since your rep is 101 I will be so bold as to suggest that you not limit yourself so narrowly to the choices given when neither one works very well, for one reason or another.

Comment: Thanks aparente001! I appreciate your advice. Yep, I'm new here and have had most of my experience on Stack Overflow where the question and answer requirements are a lot more strict in that users generally aren't looking for alternative solutions to the specific question they've asked. Thanks again! :)

Comment: We try to send people away using English better than they did before they came.  Similarly with editing other people's posts.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I say in this situation:

> I didn't see your email until now.

As a variant, you could also say:

> I didn't see your email earlier.

You could add "I was out" but I personally don't think it's necessary.  You could have been cooking, doing a jigsaw puzzle, having a conversation -- there is no law that says you have to be constantly monitoring your email.